# Complex select on a single column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table

```
create table customers(id int, cust text, email id, cust_grp int);
```

and I use the following select query to get 3 results in 3 different conditions

```
select count(*) as cust_with_email 
from customers where email<>'' and cust_grp=101;

result
--------
199

select count(*)  as cust_without_email  
from customers where email='' and cust_grp=101;
result
--------
3370

select count(*)  as cust_total 
from customers where  cust_grp=101;
result
--------
3569
```

But now I need to combine these three queries into a single select and the expected output is:

```
 custemaildet
---------------------
3569|199|3370
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [`case when`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) to filter `email` *column* and concatenate the result using `|` symbol

```
SELECT count(*) || '|' || count(CASE 
            WHEN email <> ''
                THEN email
            END) || '|' || count(CASE 
            WHEN email = ''
                THEN email
            END) custemaildet
FROM customers 
WHERE cust_grp= 101
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*)  as cust_total,
       sum(case when email = '' then 1 else 0 end) as cust_without_email ,
       sum(case when email <> '' then 1 else 0 end)  as cust_with_email    
from customers
where cust_grp = 101
```

If you want one column, then you can concat them together:

```
select concat(count(*), '|',  
              sum(case when email = '' then 1 else 0 end), '|', 
              sum(case when email <> '' then 1 else 0 end)
             )    
from customers
where cust_grp = 101
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(*), count(email = '' OR NULL), count(email <> '' OR NULL)
FROM customers
WHERE cust_grp = 101;
```

Or, In PG 9.4+:

```
SELECT
    count(*),
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE email = ''),
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE email <> '')
FROM customers
WHERE cust_grp = 101;
```